# How to correctly use PHP to listen for incoming socket connection?

Tags: php, sockets

I need to create a socket server to listen for some incoming data. I've created a PHP called socketSetup and execute it after page load. The file itself is located in a subdirectory, I need to bind the socket to an address.

Is this possible like this? My main query lies with how I'm binding it... do I just bind it to the main domain or the subdirectory?

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

socket_bind($sock, "http://mydomain.com/mysubdirectory, 80) or die('Could not bind to address');
```

Thanks

Comment: http://devzone.zend.com/209/writing-socket-servers-in-php/

Comment: @DanyCaissy Sure, but thats not what I'm asking. I'm asking, the address I'm binding too.. is it just the domain or the exact directory where the PHP file is listening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
**...::: To which *address* should I bind my server application? :::...**
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
**Recommended: *0.0.0.0*** // Binds at every available address.

If you know what you're doing then, you should use the **ip assigned to your machine by your router**. This is desired only if you're waiting for packets outside your *Local Network*.
Otherwise you should bind at 127.0.0.1

The IP assigned to your machine will look like this.
example: 192.168.1.5
netmask: 255.255.255.0 <-- ignore this

*Finding it, the easy way:*

> You can retrieve the address with `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` but you
>   shouldn't rely on it.

*Finding it, the hardcoded way:*

> On windows: type **ipconfig /all** and search for the **IPv4 Address** entry. 
>   On linux  : type **ifconfig** 
>   If you don't have access to the console then use **phpinfo()**; <- not sure about that

**Binding on** `http://www.example.com/dir/` **is wrong and it will not work, ever.**

> ***CAUTION:*** The machine doesn't know anything about the external ip ( the one assigned to you by the DSLAM i.e *128.31.53.90* ), mainly
>   because that's the routers job.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
**...::: To which *port* should I bind my server application? :::...**
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> When a client sends data to you, they arrive **first** at your router
>   who then decides what to do with them. The decision is based on your
>   routers NAT table and the incoming port.

The NAT table usually looks like this:

```
+==============================================+
|   LAN IP   |  Incoming Port  | Outgoing Port |
+============+=================+===============+
|192.168.1.5 |       8080      |       80      |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+
|192.168.1.2 |       25        |       25      |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

Let X a packet with the following structure:

```
         Header            Data
 +===================+===============+
|-| Your External IP |      ...      |
|X|                  |      ...      |
|-| Destination Port |      ...      |
 +===================+===============+
```

The router will take `destination port` and search for an a similar `incoming port` entry in the table

If it finds one then it will **redirect** the packet to the matched LAN IP : Outgoing Port

For instance:

> A packet arrives with destination port 8080, it will be forwarded to 192.168.1.5:80.
>
> ```
>        >>                    25          >>       192.168.1.2:25
> ```

Therefore, to catch the packets send by someone at 8080 you need to bind at 192.168.1.5:80,
or 25 if you're waiting for packets at port 25.

> ***CAUTION:*** Binding at port **80 WILL FAIL** if you're running a **webserver** because
>  they are bound by default to that port (unless you changed it).

Comment: @JoelKidd The answer is not yet ready. I'm still working to make as clear as possible.

Comment: Thanks very much. Do you use Skype or another form of IM I could contact you over? I might be able to pay you for a little bit of your time. My Skype username is: jskidd3

Comment: @jskidd3 I use Skype :P. Add me if you need further assistance. username: isomorphix7. I do not require payment :P